# Render node from Controller

Tags: 8, theming, page-controller

I have a controller that passes a list of nodes to a template for rendering. I think I'm missing something simple.

I've tried this with no success:

```
public function content() {
  $students = $this->getStudents();

  return [
    '#theme' => 'dashboard',
    '#students' => $students,
  ];
}

private function getStudents() {
  $user = $this->currentUser();

  $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type','student')
    ->condition('uid', $user->id())
    ->execute();
  $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
  return $nodes;
}
```

I have a dashboard theme function:

```
function dashboard_theme() {
  return [
    'dashboard' => [
    'variables' => ['students' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

And a twig template being called:

```
<ul>
  {% for student in students %}
  <li>{{ student }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This blows up the page with the error `Object of type Drupal\node\Entity\Node cannot be printed`, which is no surprise, I'm just not sure what/how to send a proper object to twig.

Answer (score 5):

Of course as soon as I posted this I figured an answer. This looks a little ugly, but I guess this is the way to go:

```
public function content() {
  $nodes = $this->getStudents();

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $student = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('node')
      ->view($node);
    $students[] = render($student);
  }

  return [
    '#theme' => 'dashboard',
    '#students' => $students,
  ];
}
```

Basically, I'm looping through the list of nodes, getting the view builder on each, then calling the `render` function and adding it to a new array. I had stumbled on this earlier because I was using `viewMultiple`, which output another array...

If you have a cleaner implementation with `viewMultiple` let me know.